# How do I get flutterfire configure command to work?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm developing in flutter and am trying to add firebase to my flutter project.

Firebase login works, auth works, dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli works and flutterfire. I can call on firebase or flutterfire and it will list the options I have so I know the paths and installs are working.

But when I run flutterfire configure I always get this:

'''

> flutterfire configure
> i Found 0 Firebase projects.
> FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
> COMMAND: firebase --version
> ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.
> '''

I've been struggling with this for a few days now and have tried firebase binary, npm, nodejs, and anything else I can find. Nothing seems to be working.

Thanks ahead of time!

Lance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue some months Ago. This happens when you have ever initialise firebase on that project,  be it for hosting , cloud function e.t.c.

Here is what you should do.

**Firstly**

Carefully delete files and folders relating to firebase-tools on that project (.firebase , firebase.json , .firebaserc ,functions(if available) and firebase_options.dart (if available));

**You can then run your**

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

flutterfire configure
```

**then incase the you are using flutter web and you care to deploy on firebase hosting**

You can now your

`firebase init;`

note:- `firebase init;` should on be done after
`flutterfire configure`

Comment: Theodore, thank you for your response! However I don't seem to have any  .firebase files in my Flutter Project directory on my computer that I can find anywhere. Would they be anywhere else?

Comment: In case it matters, firebase is already being used to deploy this app to the web and it's working fine. It's just the flutterfire configure that gives me this error.

Comment: That's the issue. Kindly add a screenshot of your folder structure

Comment: Theodore, please see the following of my Flutter project root directory.

Comment: It won't let me upload an image unfortunately so I'll list out my flutter project root directory on my PC: 

_dart_tool, .idea, .vscode, android, assets, build, build web, ios, lib, linus, macos, test, web, windows, .flutter_plugins, .flutter_plugins_dependencies, .gitignore, .metadata, .analysis_options, pubspec.lock, pubspec, README, recess_pwa.iml

Comment: Where was firebase initialized for web host

Comment: build/web is where I initialized it

I actually looked into what you said, started over, uninstalled some things, and was able to get flutterfire configure to work after fixing npm. Thansk Theodore!

Comment: Am glad i could help. Don't forget to tick answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I had to do the following commands in my project directory for it to work:

```
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
flutterfire configure --project=project_name-genereted_firebaseapp_number
```

Answer (score 0):

dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

flutterfire configure

this works for me